# Windows Store WebView Alternative

Tags: c#, webview, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am using the WebView extensively in a project but find its shortcomings to be a showstopper for the project. Are there any alternatives that can render HTML in windows store apps?

Edit: As requested, some of the problems we have with this control:

- It has no dependency property support, you need to call the methods (workaround needed: wrap it in a custom control, or attached properties...)
- It cannot render local html files (workaround with navigatetostring)
- If local html files contain extra files, like css or js, you need more workarounds to make it work
- It is a IE10 rendered above your application so it covers other controls (again you need that awful - sorry - webbrush workaround)
- Animations do not work well when put in a Listview (scrolls faster than other controls, also stretches weird), there is no workaround
- Animations do not work at all when put in an animated flyout, there is no workaround
- It breaks semantic zooming in portrait mode (besides needing the webbrush workaround for it to work) for unknown reasons if you zoom in. It works in landscape and in portrait as long as you do not navigate anything, but do not never anytime navigate a website and it breaks the zooming.

There are probably more issues we had, these are the ones that made us consider it a showstopper

Comment: Could you clarify the "shortcomings"? It's IE10 based. (There aren't really any easily used alternatives for traditional Windows desktop applications).

Comment: @WPCoder added some of the problems we had

Comment: An option is to create an app with javascript/html5. This way you have much more possibilities to display html...

Comment: I admit the `WebView` component has issues, but much of that list works:
2. Yes it can, if packaged with your app use `ms-appx-web:///` at the beginning, else make sure your app has access to the file.
3. Yes, they work, just make them relative to the html file

Comment: @James Yes, but you almost always need a workaround (as i wrote). We are downloading zipped HTML from the web, so including it in the app is not the way we can get this to work.

Comment: @UrbanEsc Right, well I have no experience of showing local non-app files in a `WebView`. I would recommend looking for a webkit project compatible with Windows Store core .net; maybe this? http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/a-real-net-4-0-webbrowser/ but I haven't tested it.

Comment: for the local content (and even online content), you can use a IUriToStreamResolver in conjonction of the WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri method

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem but solved it with the much more, not "*shortcoming*" alternative in this [XAML Toolkit for WinRT](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/).

There is a `WebBrowser` control you must have a look at.

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but the documentation for the XAML Toolkit describes the WebBrowser controls as just a wrapper for the existing WebView control with some extras for managing history, address bar, title and favicon. It wouldn't therefore be any help for the OP's problems as far as I can tell.